# How would I go about saying: "I am not at liberty to say" or "I am not at liberty to discuss"

Tags: translation, meaning-in-context

It occurs to me that this would be an useful phrase to politely decline someone who is trying to pry.  I'm l a beginner, so it's hard for me know how to translate this.

Comment: see online dictionaries, e.g. iciba  http://www.iciba.com/not%20at%20liberty

Answer (score 1):

> “I am not at liberty to say” or “I am not at liberty to discuss”

(這個/ 這件事) 我不方便說 = (This/ on this topic,) I am not at liberty to talk

(這個/ 這件事) 我不方便討論 = (This/ on this topic,) I am not at liberty to discuss

'不方便' literally means 'not convenient'  (as an adverb, it means ‘cannot conveniently) - it implies 'cannot freely'. It is a polite way to refuse to make any comment

Answer (score 0):

Here’s an alternative option, albeit a bit cheeky:

**天机不可泄露**

*[CC-CEDICT](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?page=worddict&wdrst=0&wdqtm=0&wdqcham=2&wdqt=%E5%A4%A9%E6%9C%BA%E4%B8%8D%E5%8F%AF%E6%B3%84%E9%9C%B2)* does, actually, define it:

> I am not at liberty to inform you.

——

You could also consider:

**无可奉告**

Which *[CC-CEDICT](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?page=worddict&wdrst=0&wdqtm=0&wdqcham=2&wdqt=%E6%97%A0%E5%8F%AF%E5%A5%89%E5%91%8A*)* defines as:

> (idiom) "no comment"

Comment: saying 天机不可泄露 instead of  這事我不便透露 is like saying 山人自有妙計 instead of 我自有辦法